# How to deal with rendered html items using AngularJS

Tags: php, angularjs

I use PHP on the server which returns a list of items.
Now I like to use AngularJS to modify these items.

Is there an Angular specific approach to attach inline data of each item?
I could solve this by using the html data property, but accessing those properties is quite ugly.

```
<article -->>angular item data model<--- ?>
  <div>date</div>
  <div>title</div>
  <div>content</div>
</article>
```

How would you solve this **without rendering the items list using Angular** please?

Comment: You're getting the HTML from your server? What exactly is "inline data of each item"?

Comment: @soroush: I don't want to render things client side

Comment: @New Dev: by Inline data i mean item specific data such as the database ID.

Comment: @daslicht, I don't understand at all... can you show what this "list of items" that your server returns, when does it happen, (is it an API or page load), how does this "inline data" look like and where it's coming from...

Comment: I just like to use Angular to modify existing data not to display it.

Comment: For example if you render a list ob blog posts with php the server returns something like this:https://gist.github.com/daslicht/ffaef067b0ff05adfb28
If you like to modify the content on client side and save it back to the server you would need at lest the database ID or some kind of other identifier such as a slug etc.

For that we could use the html data property such as data-id="18".
I wonder if there is something build into angular to takle such kind of cases.

Comment: @soroush gholamzadeh I know , the question is how to get the data into the controller

Comment: @soroush gholamzadeh see above ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

put it in your `article` tag:

```
ng-init="post_id = your post id;"
```

and then in your angular controller you'll have the `$scope.post_id`.

Comment: Thats exactly what I was looking for, I just created a controller and called it with the appropriate data , thank you

Comment: @daslicht your welcome! Sorry if I didn't understand it well at first ;)

Comment: anything thing fine, you are in freenode?

Comment: @daslicht No,give me the link and I'll be there soon!I mean the channel name :D

Comment: I mean the IRC chat , either use the webchat or a irc client :
https://webchat.freenode.net 
room: #angularjs :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use angular variable as inline data like -

```
<article class="{{article.class}}">
```

Put all articles inside ng-repeat and get inline data from server and assign as mentioned above.You can use `ng-class` as well.

Comment: Thank you for the reply, but the question is to find an approach without client side rendering.